# How to get the success file for Amazon Mechanical Turk for hits created using website interface?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

Hi I have created an external survey on Amazon Mechanical Turk. I want to review the hits using a script on my computer. How do I get the success-file for use with the "getResult" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you created a HIT using the Requester Website (http://requester.mturk.com) and now would like to gather the results using the Command Line Tools (https://requester.mturk.com/developer/tools/clt).

The Requester Website and CLT aren't designed to talk to one another, but you can work around that. A .success file, at its core, is really just a text file with a list of HIT IDs in them. You can create this just by opening a text editor (on Windows you can use Notepad, say) and inserting the following:

```
hitid
3MQY1YVHS3KHSD7PDPJN282PQSEB2X
```

And then save it. You can then run getResults using that .success file (if you're unsure, edit the getResults.bat on Windows or getResults file on Linux/Mac and make sure it points to the .success file you just created.

From then on, you should be able to use the command line tools to get results, process assignments, and ultimately dispose of the HITs.

I hope that helps!